# Recursive parameter pack functions without parameters C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a recursive parameter pack function as follows:

```
template <class T, class ... Ts>
void myFunction()
{
    execute<T>();

    myFunction<Ts...>();
}
```

This doesn't compile with the error:

```
error C2672: 'Test::myFunction': no matching overloaded function found.
```

Does anyone know how to do what I'm trying to achieve?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use C++17 or newer, you can skip the recursion and use a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) like

```
template<class... Ts>
void myFunction()
{
    (execute<Ts>(), ...);
}
```

Comment: Welp, that does look a lot better. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: @Niodyan Glad to help.  This was a feature added specifically because of the pains you were having trying to deal with using the individual members of the parameter pack.

Comment: Recursion can be dropped, even in C++11. It is just the way to simulate fold expression which is verbose and ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Alright I was close, this works:

```
template<class T>
void execute()
{
    // Do whatever
}

template <class T>
void myFunction()
{
    execute<T>();
}
template<class First, class Second, class... Rest>
void myFunction()
{
    myFunction<First>();

    myFunction<Second, Rest...>();
}
```